# Como destruir todas as sessões do PHP

Tags: php

Alguém sabe como destruir **todas** as sessões do PHP? Aquelas que são criadas com

```
$_SESSION = 'valor_qualquer';
```

Comment: Dê uma lida na documentação da função [`session_destroy`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-destroy.php).

Comment: Todas sessões de diferentes usuários ou todos os dados de uma sessão especifica?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

session_destroy() destrói todos os dados associados com a sessão atual. Ela não apaga nenhuma das variáveis globais associadas à sessão atual, nem apaga o cookie de sessão. Para usar as variáveis de sessão novamente, session_start() deve ser chamada.

Nota: Não é necessário chamar session_destroy() em um código habitual. Ao invés de destruir os dados da sessão, limpe o array $_SESSION.

```
<?php
// Inicializa a sessão.
// Se estiver sendo usado session_name("something"), não esqueça de usá-lo agora!
session_start();

// Apaga todas as variáveis da sessão
$_SESSION = array();

// Se é preciso matar a sessão, então os cookies de sessão também devem ser apagados.
// Nota: Isto destruirá a sessão, e não apenas os dados!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

// Por último, destrói a sessão
session_destroy();
?>
```

Fonte: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-destroy.php

Comment: Valeu cara! isso resolve o problema.

Comment: é nos, qualquer coisa estamos ai. @Jackson